# package footbib error: missing \bibitem, when using plainnat style

Tags: errors, footbib

I use the `footbib` package to do references for an acknowledgment page. This keeps the references self contained in a footnote.

If I use the plainnat style then it breaks. I have a working example which needs two files (I'm guessing it can be done in one, but I'm not sure how).

latex file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[oneside,firstcite(page)]{footbib}

\footbibliographystyle{nature} 
%\footbibliographystyle{plainnat} 
\footbibliography{references}
\renewcommand*\putfootcitelabel[1]{#1} 

\begin{document}
   Hello\footcite{Muller1993}
\end{document}
```

The second file called `references.bib` is:

```
@BOOK{Muller1993,
  title = {Inorganic Sructural Chsmistry},
  publisher = {John Wiley \& Sons Ltd.},
  year = {1993},
  author = {Ulrich M\"{u}ller},
}
```

So to compile you do **latex** -> **bibtex** on the `<project>.fb.aux` file -> **latex** -> **latex**. The `<project>.aux` file doesn't matter.

Now there is a commented out line in the project file `\footbibliographystyle`. If you swap it with the commented one, then it breaks after you try to do a latex compile following the bibtex one.

I get this error:
`! Package footbib Error: Missing \bibitem on input line 2 of footbib_test.fb.bbl.`

Any one know why or how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- I want to recommend the package `biblatex`.
- You can edit the file `<foo>.fb.bbl` manually. Than you have to change the order at the beginning:

**BEFORE**

```
\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\providecommand{\natexlab}[1]{#1}
\providecommand{\url}[1]{\texttt{#1}}
\expandafter\ifx\csname urlstyle\endcsname\relax
  \providecommand{\doi}[1]{doi: #1}\else
  \providecommand{\doi}{doi: \begingroup \urlstyle{rm}\Url}\fi
```

**AFTER**

```
\providecommand{\natexlab}[1]{#1}
\providecommand{\url}[1]{\texttt{#1}}
\expandafter\ifx\csname urlstyle\endcsname\relax
  \providecommand{\doi}[1]{doi: #1}\else
  \providecommand{\doi}{doi: \begingroup \urlstyle{rm}\Url}\fi
\begin{thebibliography}{1}
```

- Copy the file `plainnat.bst` in your working folder an change the function

`FUNCTION {begin.bib}` as follows:

```
FUNCTION {begin.bib}
{   preamble$ empty$
    'skip$
    { preamble$ write$ newline$ }
  if$
  "\providecommand{\natexlab}[1]{#1}"
  write$ newline$
  "\providecommand{\url}[1]{\texttt{#1}}"
  write$ newline$
  "\expandafter\ifx\csname urlstyle\endcsname\relax"
  write$ newline$
  "  \providecommand{\doi}[1]{doi: #1}\else"
  write$ newline$
  "  \providecommand{\doi}{doi: \begingroup \urlstyle{rm}\Url}\fi"
  write$ newline$
  "\begin{thebibliography}{" number.label int.to.str$ * "}" *
  write$ newline$
}
```

`plainnat` should be used in combination with `natbib`.

Finally I want to repeat my offer: Change to `biblatex`

Comment: Thanks for this solution Marco, I found the biblatex package to be too complicated to deal with though. I have to submit my thesis in a week and the package gave warnings about most of my references and threw up 120 errors with unhelpful messages. Maybe for another project, when I'm starting from scratch.